# What is the quickest way to group by and get the MAX of something in c#?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, c#-4.0

I am inserting new elements into a database where the primarry key is a barcode combined with a version Number. If i just insert them and use a fake version number this takes me 9 minutes for a small file, However if i use the linq statement i provided to calculate the version number this jumps up to 30minutes in a clean database and this is getting slightly worse if the database is prepopulated. Is there a better way to do the version number?

```
var results = from p in dataContext.GetTable<mailsortEntity>()
                              where p.Barcode == barcode
                              group p by p.Barcode into g
                              select new { currentVersionNo = g.Max(p => p.VersionNo) };
```

Comment: What is the underlying table and SQL that is issued please?

Comment: The table is basicly a big table with varchars, the PK is the combination of Barcode and version. we are using SQL 2008 if thats what you asked

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given that you're already restricting the bar code, your grouping is pointless. Basically your query can be simplified to:

```
var version = dataContext.GetTable<mailSortEntity>()
                         .Where(p => p.Barcode == barcode)
                         .Max(p => p.VersionNo);
```

EDIT: If you need to allow for situations where the barcode isn't in the database at all, you can use a nullable form:

```
var version = dataContext.GetTable<mailSortEntity>()
                         .Where(p => p.Barcode == barcode)
                         .Max(p => (int?) p.VersionNo);
```

(Assuming `p.VersionNo` is `int`).

That will make `version` a `Nullable<int>` with a null value if the barcode isn't in the database.

Now without the "where" clause, it makes more sense to have the grouping - but you only need the version part, so you can change the grouping:

```
var results = from p in dataContext.GetTable<mailsortEntity>()
              group p.VersionNo by p.Barcode into g
              select g.Max();
```

On the other hand that won't tell you which version number is the maximum for which bar code, so you may want:

```
var results = from p in dataContext.GetTable<mailsortEntity>()
              group p.VersionNo by p.Barcode into g
              select new { Barcode = g.Key, CurrentVersion = g.Max() };
```

I have no idea whether these will improve your query *performance*, but they're more logical representations of your query, which may make it easier to track down what's going on in terms of performance using SQL profiling etc.

Comment: your first solution seems to have problems if the barcode is not yet in the database, Is there a way to get around it without changing the entity?